# Codeigniter views not refreshing

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter site running. Once a user has performed an action on a page, that page seems to remain chached in the browser and no data on the page refreshes. Even if a record is added to or removed from a grid on the page, it will not display. I've printed out the variables on the pages and the new data is always there. I've tried forcing the browser to refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

This has had no effect. Below is an example of an insert and select with the views:

Add new record controller:

```
function add_new() {
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $data = array(

        'catalogue_name' => $_POST['catalogue_name'] ,
        'creation_date' => $current_date
        );
    $this->load->model('catalogue_model');
    $last_id = $this->catalogue_model->add_catalogue($data);
    $data['catalogue_id'] = $last_id;
    redirect('catalogues/edit/'.$last_id);
}
```

Model:

```
function add_catalogue($data){

    $this->db->insert('catalogue', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="searchable-container">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/catalogues/add_new'); ?>" method="POST" role="form" id="name_catalogue">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label>Catalogue Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="catalogue_name" id="catalogue_name" class="form-control" title="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Create Catalogue</button>
            </div>
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the select and display controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->output->set_template('default');
    $data['catalogues'] = $this->catalogue_model->get_catalogues();
    $this->load->view('catalogues/list', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_catalogues() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('catalogue');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('message')) :?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ; ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success" href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/catalogues/new_catalogue'); ?>" role="button">Add New Catalogue</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">   
            <?php foreach ($catalogues as $catalogue): ?>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h4><?php echo $catalogue->catalogue_name ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h4><?php echo $catalogue->creation_date ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default" href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/catalogues/edit'); ?>/<?php echo $catalogue->id; ?>" role="button">View</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/catalogues/delete_catalogue'); ?>/<?php echo $catalogue->id; ?>" role="button">Delete Catalogue</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        </div>
        <?php 
        $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
        $catalogue_id = $this->uri->segment($last);  
        ?>              
    </div>
</div>
```

So when adding a record here, the record shows in the database, but does not show in the view once you go to the "list" page. If I use `print_f` to print out the data, the new data is printed, but not displayed in the html.

It doesn't seem like a codeigniter problem, but I might be wrong. I'm using bootstrap 3 for the theme.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />


        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />




    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/assets/themes/default/hero_files/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/themes/default/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/themes/default/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">




        <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/themes/default/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/themes/default/js/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/grocery_crud/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap/dropdown.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/themes/default/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="/assets/themes/default/images/facebook-thumb.png"/>
    <link rel="image_src" href="/assets/themes/default/images/facebook-thumb.png" />
    <style type="text/css">


    </style>

</head>
```

Comment: if you put `echo "<pre>"; print_r($catalogues); echo "</pre>";` before `foreach()` how many records it showing

Comment: It is showing 4 records, but only 3 of them show in the page content. I've tried this previously to test. If I refresh the page 30 minutes later, 4 records show in the page content and the `print_r` output.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post, This happens on all the views throughout the website, not only on this one.

Comment: clear your caches and try

Comment: Have you got errors turned on? I'm wondering if there is a hidden error which you're not seeing that might help. Have you turned on db caching? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by moving to a new hosting provider. The hosting provider changed their hosting environment and the codeigniter sessions stopped working. This has happened before with another codeigniter program of mine. So if you experience similar issues, set up a localhost or hosting on another server and test your code there.

Other ways to identify this problem. If your program allows users to only see data they created, Logging in with different usernames will display the same or all data.

Log into the program on one browser, go to a record that requires authentication to view, copy and paste that url into a different browser. If you see the page, your sessions are not working properly.